# Can I use Skydrive to sync a folder of my chosing?

Tags: windows-7, sync

I want to sync `c:\mydir` to the cloud using SkyDrive. Can it be done?

During the SkyDrive install it allowed me to pick a folder so I chose `c:\mydir` but now SkyDrive syncs `c:\mydir\SkyDrive` not `c:\mydir`.

Is there any way to get SkyDrive to sync a folder of *my* chosing?

I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with SkyDrive, at least without third party additions or using the command prompt.

A great alternative to SkyDrive that **does** allow this is [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync).

If you absolutely need to use SkyDrive, here are a couple ways to do it (note that both of these do essentially the same thing, and neither are compatible with Windows 8.1 or later):

### SkyShellEx (http://ssx.codeplex.com/)

After installing, this program allows you to right-click on a folder and select `Sync to Skydrive`.

> From SkyDrive’s point of view, the directory itself appears in the SkyDrive directory, so SkyDrive syncs it normally.

### Using the Command Line

> You don’t need a third-party utility, though. You can do the dirty work yourself with a single command from the Windows Command Prompt. The SkyShellEx utility creates a “directory junction” on the Windows NTFS file system – the junction points to a directory elsewhere on the system. From SkyDrive’s point of view, the directory itself appears in the SkyDrive directory, so SkyDrive syncs it normally.
>   For example, to sync the folder located at D:\Folder with SkyDrive, you’d run the following command in a Command Prompt window:
>
> `mklink /J "%UserProfile%\SkyDrive\Folder" "D:\Folder"`

Hopefully these help!

Source: [How To Sync Any Folder To SkyDrive, And How To Use SkyDrive On Windows XP](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/sync-folder-skydrive-skydrive-windows-xp/)

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no on SU, due to possible future link rot. Please include the pertinent information directly in your answer, and then link the site as a source.

Comment: @techie007 I've changed my answer to include some more detailed info. Better?

Comment: @ethan I tried Bittorrent Sync. It had everything I wanted and was superb in every way, except it didn't work! On my Windows 7 machine it would sometimes only sync 10% of the files in a folder.

Comment: @NigelAlderton That's strange—it's always worked perfectly for me!

Comment: @NigelAlderton If it was a while ago when you tried BitTorrent Sync, you might want to try it again as it's come a long way in a short time. Another service that might work, though I haven't tried it myself, is LogMeIn's Cubby. (https://www.cubby.com/).

Comment: Maybe it's something about my setup but BTSync just stops indexing files containing lots of files and folders. I tried the latest version yesterday.

Comment: FYI, the command line example won't work as-is; you need to use straight quotes: `mklink /j "%UserProfile%\SkyDrive\Folder" "D:\Folder"`

Comment: Another thing I subtly hinted in my previous comment: rather than relying on `C:\Users\USERNAME` (Windows might not be installed in the `C:` drive, or the user name might not match the actual folder name) you can use the `%UserProfile%` [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows) instead.

Comment: @and31415 so it would be `mklink /J "%UserProfile%\SkyDrive\Folder" "D:\Folder"`?

Comment: Yes, just like that.